# Simple Javascript and CSS Popup for HTML not working

Tags: javascript, css, popup

Here is my [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amjath/hwDGX/2/) sample for your reference.

HTML:

```
<a href='' class="photoclick"><h2><b>Click Here to See Popup! </b></h2></a> <br/>
<div class="popup">
    <div class="content">
        <img src="http://www.ge.com/ar2012/img/close-button-large.png" alt="quit" class="closephoto" id="closephoto" style="width:25px; height:25px"/>
        <p>
        Welcome Welcome Welcome Welcome Welcome Welcome Welcome
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    var overlay = $('<div id="photooverlay"></div>');

    $('.closephoto').click(function () {
        $('.popup').hide();
        overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
        return false;
    });

    $('.photoclick').click(function () {
        overlay.show();
        overlay.appendTo(document.body);
        $('.popup').show();
        return false;
    });
});
```

I tried running on browser, all I see is the grey out background nothing else.
Please check my jsfiddle and tell me what's the issue

Edit: MY master page has

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

still i can see only gray background only

Edit2: I have this on one of my asp Content page.My master page has

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Still I see only grey background

Comment: You have no jQuery loaded in your jsfiddle. When I load jQuery, I do see a pop-up. What is exactly the issue?

Comment: I see pop up when I add a jquery library see this http://jsfiddle.net/hwDGX/3/

Comment: My Master page has 
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
So Why dont I see the popup, all I see the grey background

Comment: In js fiddle top left we have FrameWorks and Extensions below that, there are two select boxes in that 
First select box -> select jQuery1.11.0
Second Select box -> select onload option
http://jsfiddle.net/amjath/hwDGX/2/

Comment: See my OP i have edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed having a jQuery library before the code and you have not imported or added a jQuery library in the fiddle itself.

```
      $(function(){});
```

You will need jQuery included before it's called.

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hwDGX/4).

Comment: See I have edited the fiddle. Just make sure you are calling the jquery before the function call.

Comment: Do I need to call jquery in content page when I have it in Master page right??

Comment: If you check the view source of the page and dont find that link before the code then please include it you content page as well, I cannot know the structure of your project.

Comment: I'm using the above code on asp page. So I have all the jquery script on my master page. If the Jquery framework is called on Master page the why do I need to add on content page as well

Comment: See if the content page is enclosed within the master page then no need for it. But if you have a head section in the content page and the url is different please include it. I guess your master page is not a template page for the content page.

Comment: My master page is the template page for the content page. Also no head section on content page

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52675/discussion-between-sss-and-amjath)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZAt7D/). Add jQuery in your HTML:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm using the above code on asp page. So I have all the jquery script on my master page. If the Jquery framework is called on Master page the why do I need to add on content page as well

Answer (score 0):

When I zoomed out all the way I found the popup sneaking on the right side of the page. 
Sorry for the trouble guys. Carry on